# How to set up a private cocoapod to share our SDK privately

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

I am trying to share a private SDK using a spec repo and cocoapods that we can use on all our projects.

I created a dummy/test SDK (DummySDK) by creating a new Cocoatouch static library Xcode project. There is no code in the project yet. I didn't add a pod file or any other code.

I added the project to bitbucket `(https://bitbucket.org/foo/dummysdk)`. The project file is located at `https://bitbucket.org/foo/dummysdk/DummySDK.xcodeproj` and the .h file is located at `https://bitbucket.org/grantspilsbury/dummysdk/dummysdk/dummysdk.h`

I then added a license file and pushed it to bit bucket `(https://bitbucket.org/foo/dummysdk/license.txt`), as well as the tag 1.0 for the version.

I then added the following spec file to bitbucket (as a ruby file) at `https://bitbucket.org/foo/podspecs/PodSpec/1.0/PodSpec.podspec`

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = 'PodSpec'
  s.version      = '1.0'
  s.summary      = 'Lightweight ad mediation for iOS'
  s.author = {
    'Grant' => 'myemail@here.com'
  }
  s.source = {
    :git => 'https://foo@bitbucket.org/foo/testsdk.git',
    :tag => '1.0'
  }
  s.source_files = 'Source/*.{h,m}'
  s.homepage     = "http://www.testsdk.com"
  s.license      = "MIT"
  s.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "license.txt" }
  s.requires_arc = true
end
```

I then ran the command `> ~/Source/PodSpecs/PodSpec/1.0$ pod repo add PodSpecs https://bitbucket.org/foo/podspecs` (from where the spec file is located)

I then ran `>~/.cocoapods/repos/PodSpecs$ pod repo lint .` (from the root folder of the spec file

I got the output message:

```
Linting spec repo `PodSpecs`
.
Analyzed 1 podspecs files.
All the specs passed validation.
```

I then removed and added the spec file again because I added the license file earlier

```
pod repo remove PodSpecs
```

and then ran `> ~/Source/PodSpecs/PodSpec/1.0$ pod repo add PodSpecs https://bitbucket.org/foo/podspecs`

I then tried to push the pod spec file by running:

```
>~/Source/PodSpecs/PodSpec/1.0$ pod repo push PodSpecs PodSpec.podspec --verbose
```

and I got the following message:

```
Validating spec
[!] The `PodSpec.podspec` specification does not validate.

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/push.rb:91:in `rescue in block in validate_podspec_files'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/push.rb:88:in `block in validate_podspec_files'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/push.rb:85:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/push.rb:85:in `validate_podspec_files'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/push.rb:42:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.6.1/lib/claide/command.rb:281:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:48:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/bin/pod:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

I also tried `>~/Source/PodSpecs/PodSpec/1.0$ pod repo push PodSpecs PodSpec.podspec --allow-warnings`

and got the message:

```
Validating spec
[!] The `PodSpec.podspec` specification does not validate.
```

That's as far as I got. I also need to know how to include the sdk into other projects, I assume using the podfile?

I also tried changing the pod spec file name to DummySDK and using that in the pod spec file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
      s.name         = 'DummySDK'
      s.version      = '1.0'
      s.summary      = 'Lightweight ad mediation for iOS'
      s.author = {
        'Grant' => 'myemail@here.com'
      }
      s.source = {
        :git => 'https://foo@bitbucket.org/foo/testsdk.git',
        :tag => '1.0'
      }
      s.source_files = 'Source/*.{h,m}'
      s.homepage     = "http://www.testsdk.com"
      s.license      = "MIT"
      s.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "license.txt" }
      s.requires_arc = true
    end
```

But get the error:

```
~/.cocoapods/repos/PodSpecs$ pod spec lint

 -> DummySDK (1.0)
    - ERROR | [OSX] [xcodebuild]  2014-09-25 11:06:37.481 xcodebuild[6872:2403] error: InputFile    /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/SDKSettings.plist 0 1377395452 1100 33188... malformed line 7; 'InputFile' should have exactly five arguments
    - ERROR | The `source_files` pattern did not match any file.
    - ERROR | [iOS] [xcodebuild]  2014-09-25 11:06:40.900 xcodebuild[6918:3d07] error: InputFile    /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk/SDKSettings.plist 0 1407358670 911 33188... malformed line 7; 'InputFile' should have exactly five arguments
    - ERROR | [iOS] [xcodebuild]  2014-09-25 11:06:40.902 xcodebuild[6918:3d07] error: InputFile    /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk/SDKSettings.plist 0 1407358670 911 33188... malformed line 7; 'InputFile' should have exactly five arguments

Analyzed 1 podspec.
```

**EDIT**

In my sdk repository there is code but nothing really meaningful.

i.e. the .h file looks like so:

```
//
//  DummySDK.h
//  DummySDK
//
//  Created by Grant Spilsbury on 2014/09/25.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Grant Spilsbury. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DummySDK : NSObject

@end
```

The entire file structure of the sdk repository looks like this:

```
/dummysdk
/dummysdk/DummySDK
/dummysdk/DummySDK/DummySDK.h
/dummysdk/DummySDK/DummySDK.m
/dummysdk/DummySDK.xcodeproj
/dummysdk/DummySDK.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace
/dummysdk/DummySDK.xcodeproj/xcuserdata
/dummysdk/DummySDK.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
/dummysdk/DummySDKTests
```

I renamed Xcode which seemed to solve one issue but I now get the following lint error:

````
~/.cocoapods/repos/PodSpecs$ pod spec lint .

 -> DummySDK
――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

### Report

* What did you do?

* What did you expect to happen?

* What happened instead?


### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 0.33.1
        Ruby : ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
    RubyGems : 2.0.14
        Host : Mac OS X 10.9.4 (13E28)
       Xcode : 6.0 (6A313)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib
Repositories : Cocoapods - https://bitbucket.org/afrozaar/specs @ df68442fba9e1d7259248b1f2d46cc00835c6114
               PodSpecs - https://bitbucket.org/grantspilsbury/podspecs @ f3547e07e39e8a804c3a4238415cc86e5908d95f
               master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ b99e5bad41d73c1c575dc2237ac7e7eab55b0dcc
```

### Error

```
REST::DisconnectedError - end of file reached
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nap-0.8.0/lib/rest/request.rb:190:in `rescue in perform'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nap-0.8.0/lib/rest/request.rb:187:in `perform'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nap-0.8.0/lib/rest/request.rb:200:in `perform'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nap-0.8.0/lib/rest.rb:41:in `head'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods-core/http.rb:63:in `perform_head_request'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods-core/http.rb:13:in `block in get_actual_url'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods-core/http.rb:12:in `loop'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods-core/http.rb:12:in `get_actual_url'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods-core/http.rb:43:in `validate_url'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:232:in `validate_url'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:247:in `validate_homepage'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:199:in `perform_extensive_analysis'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:71:in `validate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/command/spec.rb:93:in `block in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/command/spec.rb:86:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/command/spec.rb:86:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.6.1/lib/claide/command.rb:281:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:48:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/bin/pod:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing github issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=end+of+file+reached&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!
````

Answer (score 1):

So I see two problems in your final lint:

- The `error: InputFile` messages are related to an issue regarding Xcode 6, see https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2394#issuecomment-56658587 - as a workaround, you could renamed your `Xcode 2.app` to something else which does not contain spaces.
- The `source_files` related message means that no `.h` or `.m` files actually exist in your `Source` directory. You said *"There is no code in the project yet"* early on, that will definitely cause the lint to fail.

Comment: I renamed xcode and that seemed to solve the one issue. Please have a look at my updated post with regards to the empty files

Comment: That looks there was some problem validating the homepage from the spec, might be a temporary connection problem.